# Fastest way to transform dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns:

reading_df:

```
    c1  c2  c3
    1   1   0.104986
    1   1   0.628024
    0   0   0.507727
    1   1   0.445931
    0   1   0.867830
    1   1   0.455478
    1   0   0.271283
    0   1   0.759124
    1   0   0.382079
    0   1   0.572290
```

For each element in 3 column (c3) i must find how many items(rows) are:

- have same values for c1
- have same values for c2
- differens between values in c3 in given row and each row must be less whan 0.3

For example the answer writing in column c4

```
   c1  c2  c3        c4
    1   1   0.104986  0
    1   1   0.628024  2
    0   0   0.507727  0
    1   1   0.445931  0
    0   1   0.867830  2
    1   1   0.455478  1
    1   0   0.271283  0
    0   1   0.759124  1
    1   0   0.382079  1
    0   1   0.572290  0
```

I transform dataframe into numpy array and use map function with labmda to have best performance.

```
reading_df['c4']=np.zeros(df.shape[0])

X=np.array(reading_df)

c1=0
c2=1
c3=2
dT=0.3

res_map =  map(lambda el: len( X[

    ( X[:,n_time] > (el[n_time]-dT) ) 

    & ( X[:,n_time] < (el[n_time])  )

    & ( X[:,n_feature2] == (el[n_feature2]) )

    & ( X[:,n_feature1] == (el[n_feature1]) )

                                    ][:,n_time]), X)
```

But when i try to transform map object `res_map` into list:

```
result=list(res_map)
result_dataframe=pd.DataFrame({'c4':result })
```

my code become very slow. And work very long time for big dataframe with more than 1*10^6 elements.

Which function i must use? And which the best practices to make python work faster?

Comment: Hi, do you mind to better explain  what you are trying to achieve? It's not that clear to me.

Comment: I recently read a post on LinkedIn claiming that Pandas is actually quite a bit slower than Numpy (even though Pandas uses Numpy in its core). I have not tested this, so I cannot confirm - but if you are working towards optimisations, looking into plain numpy might be useful.

Comment: @user32185 for each row i try to find how many rows have same values in c1, c2, and the c3 value that less than the value in giver row on 0.3

Comment: @BramVanroy it's true but this is not the case. Pandas is slower when you do heavy linear algebra with columns. In that case you might consider to test your code with  pandas and then translate it to a numpy approach.

Comment: @Иван Sorry but It's not clear yet. The first row as c1==c2 and c3<0.3 yet c4 is 0. If you can better clarify the problem it will be easier to find a solution.

Comment: @user32185 For example: for the second row: 1   1   0.628024  we have two row witch have same c1, c2 and c3 witch less on 0.3 it's: fourth and sixth rows (fourth: 1   1   0.445931 and sixth: 1   1   0.455478) and result for second row it's two (fourth and sixth rows). For the first row it's zero.

Comment: I still dont understand your logic, 0.445931 and 0.455478 is not less then 0.3

Comment: @Erfan Okay, the differense between 0.628024 and 0.445931 must be less when 0.3

Comment: Oke, than why is this row 2? `0   1   0.867830  2`

Comment: @Erfan because only two rows have `с1=0`, `c2=1` and `0.867830-c3<0.3` at the same time (it's `0   1   0.759124  1` and    `0   1   0.572290  0`) nine and ten row

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the exact logic is behind your question, but I think you want to `groupby` and than calculate the `diff`

If I understand your problem correctly its a `many-to-many` comparison within each group of `c1` and `c2`.

Here's a start for your prolem which you can build on:

```
# first calculate the difference between rows in c3 column while applying groupby
df['difference'] = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).c3.diff()

# then add a count column which counts the size of each group
df['count'] = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).c1.transform('count')

# after that create a conditional field based on the values in the other columns
df['c4'] = np.where((df.c1 == df.c2) & (df.difference < 0.3), 1, 0)
```

Hope this helps in terms of speed (vectorization) and closer to solve your problem.